# Angular + Django REST Authentication credentials were not provided

Tags: angularjs, django, rest, authentication, credentials

I'm developing an API with Django REST. The client is a SPA in AngularJS running in node.js. Register and Login work fine, but when the user does logout the error message is showed:

> {"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}

I tried many solutions, like [post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906630/django-rest-framework-authentication-credentials-were-not-provided) and [post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343504/django-rest-framework-detailauthentication-credentials-were-not-provided). but the problem continues. If my Angular files are in the server, my page works fine, but when I changed for a SPA created by yeoman, I have the credentials problem.

My **settings.py**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'y6u0gy4ij&8uoo6@p*$qukwp$-07@-1gd)@)(l!-j&wmpot4h#'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'authentication',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware', #
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ServerLearn.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ServerLearn.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.Account'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_URLS_REGEX = r'^/api/v1/.*$'
```

My **models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models

from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        token = Token.objects.create(user=instance)
        print(token)


class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, password=None, **kwargs):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Need username.")

        if not kwargs.get("email"):
            raise ValueError("Need email.")

        account = self.model(
            username = username,
            email = self.normalize_email(kwargs.get("email")),
            name = kwargs.get("name"),
            age = kwargs.get("age"),
            gender = kwargs.get("gender"),
            #birth = kwargs.get("birth")
        )

        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()

        return account

    #admin
    #senhaadmin
    def create_superuser(self, username, password, **kwargs):
        account = self.model(
            username = username,
            email = self.normalize_email(kwargs.get("email")),
            name = "Admin",
            age = 31111,
            gender = 555,
        )

        account.is_admin = True
        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()

        return account



class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique = True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    gender = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    #birth = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FILES = ['username', 'email', 'name', 'age', 'gender']

    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.username
```

My **views.py**

```
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'username'
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return (permissions.AllowAny(),)

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return (permissions.AllowAny(),)

        return (permissions.IsAuthenticated(), IsAccountOwner(),)

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data = request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            Account.objects.create_user(**serializer.validated_data)

            return Response(serializer.validated_data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response({
            'status': 'Bad request',
            'message': 'Conta não pode ser criada'
            }, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class LoginView(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))

        username = data.get('username', None)
        password = data.get('password', None)

        account = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if account is not None:
            if account.is_active:
                login(request, account)

                serialized = AccountSerializer(account)

                return Response(serialized.data)
            else:
                return Response({
                    'status': 'Unauthorized',
                    'message': 'This account has been disabled.'
                }, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        else:
            return Response({
                'status': 'Unauthorized',
                'message': 'Username/password combination invalid.'
            }, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)


class LogoutView(views.APIView):

    #ERROR IN NEXT LINE
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):

        logout(request)
        return Response({}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

In my Angular application, in **app.js**

```
app.run(run);

run.$inject = ['$http'];

function run($http) {
      $http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
      $http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
}
```

I get token after login with code:

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/api-token-auth/', {
    username: username,
    password: password
}).then(tokenSuccessFn, tokenErrorFn);

function tokenSuccessFn(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("token:  ");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Token ' + $cookies.get("csrftoken");                
}

function tokenErrorFn(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.error('token error !!!');
}
```

The **logout** is

```
return $http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/auth/logout/')
    .then(logoutSuccessFn, logoutErrorFn);

function logoutSuccessFn(data, status, headers, config) {
    Authentication.unauthenticate();

    window.location = '/';
}

function logoutErrorFn(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.error('Logout error !!!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'` from your DRF DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES,only use TokenAuth,if you still need browsable api,you can use chrome plugin [ModHeader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I didn't add the token to header correctly.

I get the token and storage in a local storage.

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/api-token-auth/', {
    username: username,
    password: password
}).then(tokenSuccessFn, tokenErrorFn);

function tokenSuccessFn(data, status, headers, config) {

    localStorage.setItem('myApp.token',data['data'].token);
}

function tokenErrorFn(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.error('token error !!!');
}
```

When the app (page) begins, I load the token from local storage in app.js:

```
app.run(['$http', function ($http) {


    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('myApp.token');        
}]);
```

Thanks Ykh for the help.