# When I make a POST request I'm getting "No credentials provided response"

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework, fetch

I have a django server running on Linode, I'm trying to make a POST request but all I get is `detail:"Authentication credentials were not provided."`

I already made my research and whenever I have the server in production, (port 80), it doesn't work, as soon as I make `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` it works, when I point my fetch to that URL.

```
fetch(URL,
  method ='POST',
  headers = {
    'Authorization': `Token ${this.props.token}` ,
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body= JSON.stringify( {
    user: 10,
        voltage_coil_1: 1,
        voltage_coil_2: 1,
        voltage_generated_by_user: 1,
        activity:1,
        datetime:null
})
)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(console.log)
```

My expected results are a positive answer, but whenever I'm in production, I keep getting this error.

[Server Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7myTP.png)

Comment: try `console.log(this.props.token)` to check if there is a value in it.

Comment: port 80 is a privileged one, you probably need to use `sudo` when starting the server.

Comment: When I print the token is actually there. Yeah I already did start my server with sudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this problem by adding the following on my view on Django:

```py
class DataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserData.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication]
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache as a web server in production mode, you should set WSGIPassAuthorization to 'On'.

Take a look at this link,

[Django Rest Framework {"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343504/django-rest-framework-detailauthentication-credentials-were-not-provided)

Comment: Still getting the same error, I already placed `WSGIPassAuthorization On`and doesn't work.

Comment: Can you print the authorization header of your request in the server side? I think the API view does not receive the token

Comment: Hi, I'm new at django, how do I print the authorization header?

Comment: I think this will help you `request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', b'')`

Comment: Ok. I did that, here is my code: 

```class DataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserData.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
    def post(self, request):

        print (request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', b''))
        content = {
            'response': 'response',
        }

        return Response(content)```


But all I get is `Forbidden: /api/data/
[22/Apr/2019 18:43:14] "GET /api/data/ HTTP/1.1" 403 58`

And again, thank you for your patience with me! :/
@MehranNouri

Comment: what does it print to console?

Comment: Nothing, all I get is `Forbidden: /api/data/ [22/Apr/2019 18:43:14] "GET /api/data/ HTTP/1.1" 403 58`